# webpack & output:publicpath confusion?

Tags: webpack

Watching a course on webpack on pluralsight and with how it was explained i expected the following config settings:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve('build/js/'),
    publicPath: '/public/assets/js/',
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
```

webpack to have some type of redirect that redirects the loading of dependencies. For example:

```
<script src="/public/assets/js/bundle.js">
```

I expected webpack would redirect that to `'/build/js/bundle.js'` but its not working. He was using the webpack dev server and i'm running this through visual studio with IIS Express. Does this redirect only work with the webpack dev server?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's a publicPath field on both webpack's and webpack-dev-server's config.

While the first one should tell the compiler where to "output" your bundle, the second one is merely used to extract a filename from the url you made a request at.

Basically setting them to the same value **should** work just fine.

Comment: but when i tried to use the publicPath '/public/assets/js/bundle.js' the request failed (HTTP 404)

Comment: Could you post the full config you're using for webpack and the dev-server?